# fetching two type of json files with different beginning of structure

Tags: php, json

I'm processing json file with php with little difference in the beginning of the file ,my problem now is that i built two foreach loops and i am looking for a way to make it one loop.

```
{"code":0,"rid":"0","data":{"subid":"9174906486819979969","data":{"more":


{"code":0,"rid":"0","data":{"9174906486819979969":{"more":
```

Now I'm doing like that and it double the code for processing , the rest of the json file is all the same.

```
foreach($json['data']['data'])
{

}

foreach($json['data'])
{

}
```

What i need is one foreach loop instead of 2, is that possible?

Comment: the rest of the json is valid so no need to show all the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the key and if present use it, if not then get the first key:

```
if(isset($json['data']['data'])) {
    $data = $json['data']['data'];
} else {
    $data = reset($json['data']); //or current()
}
```

Or shorter:

```
$data = $json['data']['data'] ?? reset($json['data']);
```

Then:

```
foreach($data as $values) {
    //code
}
```

Another option would be to loop and check for an array, depending on the structure you have:

```
foreach($json['data'] as $values) {
    if(is_array($values)) {
        foreach($values as $v) {
            //code
        }
}
```

Comment: thats looks promising , im going to check that in the morning , thanks :)